# What is the literal for cntrl+c (like ^[ is a literal escape) for shell script to kill the process

Tags: linux, shell

What is the literal for cntrl+c - kill process (like ^[ is a literal escape). I need to code this literal in here document of one of  shell script to get exit the control.

SOme one please help me.. :(

Comment: Use ctrl+V with ctrl+any character to get the literal sequence for any character

Comment: If you need to send a signal in a shell script, use the `kill` command or builtin.

Comment: I need to code that literal for cntrl+c in between the here document (:EOD:) ....  @BasileStarynkevitch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting shell's control break statement in the standard input stream "EOD" to exit the COBOL program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903596/setting-shells-control-break-statement-in-the-standard-input-stream-eod-to-ex)

Comment: I don't think the suggested duplicate is a good duplicate; vaguely related, rather than exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII code for ctrl-C is 3; it is often represented as `^C` but this is just a human representation consisting of the two characters `^` and `C`.

In legacy character sets, the control characters often had a graphical representation, so on an old IBM PC ([CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) you would see a heart glyph ♥ if you looked at a file containing this character.  In Unicode, it simply has [no representation at all](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03/index.htm) although some fonts contain a small box with the characters "ETX" in it (the "end of text" semantics from [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) are purely historical, however). In my browser, <<>> is simply the empty string, but yours might show something else between the angle brackets.

Putting a ctrl-C in a here document will nevertheless not generate a signal; the signal is generated by the interactive terminal driver when it receives this character (and the character can be reconfigured easily; `man stty`). When the shell parses a here document, the terminal driver is not involved at all.

To send a signal from a script, use the `kill` command.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you mean the `^C` character sequence?